# setTitleTextAttributes not working after view on screen. iOS 11

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I've spent a whole day trying to change the colour of a UIBarButtonItem and now i'm thinking it is an iOS 11 bug unless someone can tell me it's by design.

I can change the colour of the text by using this code

```
[self.refreshButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor orangeColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If I add the code to the `viewWillAppear:animated` function it works fine, however if you add it to `viewDidAppear:animated` it does not work.

It seems to work on the iOS 9 simulator, but not iOS 11.

Has something changed in this regard in iOS 11?

Comment: I got some problem when changing UI in `viewWillAppear:animated` too. I think put your code in `dispatch_after` with some delay will solve problem ;)

Comment: I’m sure I tried that and it still didn’t work. I’ll try again.

Comment: Nope, still no dice after a 1 second delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is change the title color of your `UIBarButtonItem` you can set the `tintColor` property instead of `setTitleTextAttributes:`. If you want all of your `UIBarButtonItems` to have the same title color you can set the `tintColor` of your tool/navigation bar.

Comment: `setTintColor:` works fine thanks. I have submitted a bug report to Apple about `setTitleTextAttributes:`

Comment: `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor` did the trick, thanks.

Comment: @Darren could you please put your radar id here ?

Comment: @justicepenny 35313390

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on iOS11 but needed to set the font by `setTitleTextAttributes`. Unfortunately this does also not work by appearance. The only solution I found was to create new BarButtonItems as copy of the old ones and then set them as `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems`.

For reference for other users having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46964643/7311767) may explain why the method doesn't work.

An improper setting of `UIControlState()` may be the problem.